# Lisp, calculating odd numbers

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Given a list of atoms consist of numbers and atoms of other types, how can I sum up the odd numbers in it?

```
(sum-odds '(3 6 c 5 82 29 e g) ) => 37
```

First, I think I need to somehow filter the list to get a list of numbers in it. Later I can sum the numbers in this new list.

I do not know the primitives to use it to do so, neither the way to construct the algorithm to achieve this on my own.

Comment: With [`reduce`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_reduce.htm)

Comment: What have you tried? You should show your attempt and ask a more specific question about where you're stuck.

Answer (score 4):

With a loop:

```
(loop for ... in ...
      when ...
        sum ...)
```

With higher-order functions:

```
(reduce #'+ (remove-if-not (lambda (e) ...) ...))
```

A single reduce could work too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are an absolute beginner maybe you haven't studied yet many *special forms* but I think that you could know of the `if` one, that has the syntax `(if COND THEN ELSE)`... and of course you must know `defun`!

Armed with `defun` and `if` we start with the definition of a *recursive* function, `mysum`, that sums a list of numbers, i.e., a `lon`: `(defun mysum (lon) ...)`

A recursive implementation means that we want to sum (using `+`) the first element of the list, `(car lon)`, with the sum of the remaining part of the list, `(mysum (cadr lon))`: `(+ (car lon) (mysum (cadr lon)))` — if there is a first element, of course... so we check if the list is non empty, `(if lon ...`, followed by the `THEN` clause that we have already discussed and eventually the `ELSE` clause, whose value has to be the sum of the values in an empty list, i.e., `0` so that `(+ last-value (mysum empty-list))` -> `last-value`.

```
(defun mysum (lon)
    (if lon
        (+ (car lon) (mysum (cdr lon)))
       0))
```

So, we have defined a really simple function because the list it operates is homogeneous, for a non homogeneous one, with the additional oddity thrown in, we have to be more careful and sum to the sum of the remaining part either `0` if the `car` is not an odd number or the`car` if it is an odd number,

```
(defun oddsum (mixlist)
    (if mixlist
        (+ (if (and (integerp (car mixlist)) (oddp (car mixlist))) 
               (car mixlist)
             0)
           (oddsum (cdr mixlist)))
       0))
```

Answer (score 0):

The absolute simplest is probably to just use `reduce` and a helper function:

```
(defun sum-only-odd-numbers (a b)
  (+ a  ;; Previous version checked for oddness here, that is incorrect
     (if (and (integerp b) (oddp b)) b 0))

(reduce #'sum-only-odd-numbers ... :initial-value 0)
```

Comment: I'd suggest `integerp` instead of `numberp`, as `oddp` applied to a real number says `The value … is not of type INTEGER`

Comment: `A` is the accumulator; you shouldn't check if it's odd. Otherwise `(reduce #'sum-only-odd-numbers '(1 3 5))` => `5`, because four is not odd. Although you do have to check if the first number is odd, so this approach doesn't really work out that well.

Comment: Rather than adding creating a special addition function, why not use a **key** function that takes odd integers to themselves and everything else to 0?  E.g., `(reduce '+ list :key (lambda (x) (if (and (integerp x) (oddp x)) x 0)))`.  That keeps the important part of the logic visible at the reduction site.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Either is fine. There's a slight argument for having something defined in a `defun` and that's because it's a lot easier to trace, if you need to debug things. In this case, it's probably perfectly fine to either use an externally defined sum-function, an externally defined key function, or either of those as a lambda function in the call to reduce.